# How to add description of schema in Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

The command `\dn+` shows description as `standard public schema` for `public` schema.

How can I alter the other schemas to add the description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`comment` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html):

```
comment on schema some_schema is 'This is my other schema';
```